# Fill up combobox using stored procedure in vb6

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, vb6, combobox

How to fill up combobox during runtime using stored procedure to get values from database?

here's my code, this should be converted into stored procedure:

```
Private Sub ComboFill()
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command
With Cmd
.ActiveConnection = Conn
.CommandType = adCmdText
.CommandText = "SELECT suppliername from supplier"
 Set Rs = .Execute
End With

If Not (Rs.BOF And Rs.EOF) Then
Rs.MoveFirst
End If

Do Until Rs.EOF
txtsupplier.AddItem Rs.Fields("suppliername").Value
Rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try? Google is still free.

Comment: @user2063626:already  updated the post. check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

**EDIT:** adjusted to return a RS, not a single value

```
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = Session.GetConnectionstring
cn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = “MyStoredProcdure”
' Input param, if you need
' cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(“Param1”, adInteger, adParamInput, , 614)
' Create a recordset by executing the command.
Set Rs = cmd.Execute()
Rs.MoveFirst()

Do Until Rs.EOF
    txtsupplier.AddItem Rs.Fields("suppliername").Value
Rs.MoveNext

Set Rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```